# Low quality window switcher icon

Tags: python, pyqt5

I just set a 512x512 icon to my pyQt5 application, however, the icon quality/resolution in the window switcher (when hitting alt+tab) is very low. I cannot seem to find any common solution. All examples I find just add the icon, no resolution settings etc.

Here is how I add my icon, which is probably to no surprise:

```
app_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(app_dir + os.path.sep + "icon.png"))
```

All help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to use 256×256 ICO file. This may help.

Comment: Same issue, unfortunately. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Have you tried availableSizes method? Referred here: https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QIcon.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QIcon.availableSizes

Comment: I have, when I print the result I get `PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(512, 512)`

Comment: What operating system are you using? If it's on Linux, what distro/window manager?

Comment: Linux mint, cinnamon. window manager: Mutter (Muffin)